# Undefined variable: posts when passing parameter from controller to view

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a search function in Laravel and its returning me with "undefined variable: posts" when I do foreach on my view.

My code:

**Post Model**

```
class Post extends Model { 

    protected $fillable = [ 
        'creator', 
        'post_url', 
        'books', 
        'likes', 
        'created_at' 
        ]; 

    public function user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); } 

}
```

**Homeview:**

```
<form action="{{ url('/search') }}" method="get">
   <input type="text" class="search-text form-control form-control-lg" name="q" placeholder="Search" required>
 </form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function search($keyword)
    {
        $result = Post::where('books', 'LIKE', "'%' . $keyword . '%'")->get();
        return view('/search', ['posts' => $result]);
    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/search/{keyword}', 'SearchController@search');
```

**Searchview:**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <div class="post">{{ $post->id }}</div>
@endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try return view('search')->with('posts', $results);

Comment: The problem is most likely that the controller isn't getting the keyword

Comment: Yup, thats not working. How am I supposed to pass the keyword to the controller? @DerekPollard

Comment: @Jascusi remove `$keyword` from the parameters, and use this in the method: `$keyword = request()->input('q');`

Comment: That makes more sense but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Can you dd($request->all()) on the line before this one '$result = Post::where("books", "LIKE", "%{$request->input('q')}%")->get();' in UkraineInTheMembrane's answer and paste the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you out.

**Homeview.blade.php**

```
<form action="/search" method="POST">
    @csrf // include your csrf token 

    <input type="text" class="search-text form-control form-control-lg" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Search" required>
</form>
```

**Searchview.blade.php**

```
<!-- or did you return a collection? --> 
@if( $posts->count() > 1 )

    <!-- then loop through the posts --> 
    @foreach( $posts as $post )
        <div class="post"> {{ $post->id }} </div>
    @endforeach

@else

    @if( !empty($posts) )
        <div class="post"> {{ $post->id }} </div>
    @endif 

@endif
```

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/search', 'PostsController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

**PostsController**

```
use App\Post;

public function show( Request $request )
{

    $result = Post::where("books", "LIKE", "%{$request->input('q')}%")->get();

    // Uncomment the following line to see if you are returning any data
    // dd($result);

    // Did you return any results?
    return view('searchview', ['posts' => $result]);

}
```

Comment: I dont know what I'm supposed to do? Because it gives me the same error when I putt dd($result) before the query.

Comment: I updated my answer and added a line for debugging your post route there. Can you uncomment it and tell me what it returns?

Comment: This might also seem like a silly question, but can you show me your Post model?

Comment: dd($result) would tell you whether or not you are returning data. I can't really help much more unless you uncomment it and tell me what it returns!

Comment: Sorry, didnt read your comment, my post model looks like this: class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'creator', 'post_url', 'books', 'likes', 'created_at'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

Comment: Also, as already told. DD gives the same error "Undefined variable: posts" or how am I supposed to call that function?

Comment: You're not calling dd properly if you keep seeing that error, hence the reason why I keep bringing it up. If you're using the form I provided in your _homeview_ , then when it posts to the PostsController it will show you the result of your query. Just remove the two `//` in the controller function as outlined in the answer.

Comment: Got it now! I kept refreshing the search view. I'm new to laravel so please bear with me. Heres the outcome: Collection {#246 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: No worries - everyone has to start somewhere. That's perfect - so - your post is working now, it's just returning 0 results. So when you try to loop through it in a foreach, it's returning that error. I'll edit my answer in a second here

Comment: Okay, give the updated searchview.blade.php and controller function a shot and tell me how you make out.

Comment: Now I'm not getting any errors but the normal search view with no content printed out.

Comment: NVM, when a book is found it returns the ids.

Comment: Boom! So problem solved :) I knew you had it in you! Love it when a plan comes together eh?

Comment: sure do! but how do I get it to work as a get form now so the keyword is shown in the url? really appreciate your help here btw!

Comment: You may need to fix this bit @if( $posts->count() == 1 )
    <div class="post"> {{ $post->id }} </div> if its an object there would be no count function, if its a collection you've not pulled the object out.

Comment: Good catch @ColinMD - fixed.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to show the keyword in the url @Jascusi ? Just curious. As a reminder to the user or something?

Comment: Yeah, as a reminder but also I dont want the user to submit a post form each time they refresh the search page.

Comment: @Jascusi to change to a get request you can just change the method in the form from 'POST' to 'GET' and then change the route to be this Route::get('/search', 'PostsController@show')->name('posts.show');  The $request->input() function in the controller should pick up both get and post data.

Comment: GET requests are also better than POST for search as links can be shared.  Janice can forward a link to Sharon and get the search results she was looking at, She couldn't do that with POST. (No idea who Janice or Sharon are by the way xD)

Comment: You can use [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) component to post the form without refreshing the page, if that's a concern. It's probably the way I'd go about doing this, tbh, but that's another question for sure!

Comment: @ColinMD yup, that works! thanks alot! also, after all these curiosities I still want to know why my first code didnt work? What did I do wrong because it seems like I did everything right but somehow I didnt?

Comment: Hard to write in a comment so I will post an answer

Comment: Way to try and snipe my answer @ColinMD ;)

Comment: Well @Jascusi it's been fun but I've gotta get back to my own coding ambitions here. If this answered your question, accepting it would be a boost to me but that's up to you my friend. Have a great day!

Comment: Haha oh I'm just busting your chops @ColinMD - I'm honestly just here to help and give back to this community that's helped me a lot over the years. Whatever he wants to do is no problem for me.

Comment: I'm really thankful for both of you. Thanks for helping me out here and after 5 hours of headaches I can sleep in peace. I gave @UkraineInTheMembrane the mark because he came first and also worked it all out for me :) Also thanks to you @ ColinMD for your answers. Good night everyone!

Comment: Team work makes the dream work you two. Glad we could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't working,

```
Route::get('/search/{keyword}', 'SearchController@search');
```

In your route file you were looking for a `{keyword}` that was never passed by the form.  Your form action is `action="{{ url('/search') }}"`. A get variable will not be picked up by a route and if it was you called the input 'q' anyway.

So then in your controller you were looking for the keyword being passed that is never passed in.

```
public function search($keyword)
```

Instead the correct thing to do is pass in the Request object like so

```
public function search(Request $request)
```

Then use `$request->input('q')` to retrieve the passed value through your form.

In your example `$keyword` would always have been blank.

Corrected code

Homeview:

```
<form action="{{ url('/search') }}" method="get">
   <input type="text" class="search-text form-control form-control-lg" name="q" placeholder="Search" required>
 </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $result = Post::where('books', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('q')}%")->get();
    return view('/search', ['posts' => $result]);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/search', 'SearchController@search');
```

Searchview:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <div class="post">{{ $post->id }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Thats the correct answer and after I did these steps it worked! :)

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
return view('/search')->with('posts', $result);
```

Or even better with dinamic vars.

```
return view('/search')->withPosts($result);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as the problem isn't with the way OP is passing data to the view

Comment: Sadly that isnt working, I'm getting the same error as before.

Comment: What you get when you try a dd before call the view?

dd($result);

Comment: Same error.. I have the feeling that its something really stupid and easy to solve but I dont know what.

Comment: Do you imported the Post Class?

use App\Post;

?

Comment: Yes, I imported the class.

Comment: Please, send the complete error... It's very intrigant!

Comment: Undefined variable: posts (View: /Users/xxx/Developer/test/resources/views/search.blade.php)